# linking error when trying to link with boost in debug mode using CMake and Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, cmake

I have this in my cmake file:

```
if (MSVC)
    add_definitions (-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)
else (MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif (MSVC)


#boost library
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{BOOST_DIR})
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR $ENV{BOOST_DIR}/lib64-msvc-11.0)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework thread system filesystem REQUIRED)



include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
    ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}
    )



target_link_libraries(TestIDSCamera
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    )
```

but when I try to compile my code, I am getting this error:

```
mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug'
```

How can I fix it? I want a static linkage so I don't want to ship any dll with my application.

Comment: Are the boost libraries present in `$ENV{BOOST_DIR}/lib64-msvc-11.0 ` the versions that are statically linked?

Comment: @Chad yes all libs are there.

Comment: What's the output of `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: I am using Visual studio, so no make file :(